# KVM Bridging - Network connection fails if I change Device model to VirtIO from rtl8139

Tags: networking, windows-7, 14.10, ethernet, connection

I'm setting up my first VM and am using bridging to access my network.  It's a Windows7 VM on Ubuntu 14.10. I read that changing to 'Device Model = VirtIO' in the definition of the VM will improve Ethernet performance.  When I change it to VirtIO from rtl8139, I lose Ethernet connectivity on the VM.  Any suggestions?

Side Notes: I'm new to the Linux world, as this question may indicate.  I'd actually prefer to bridge the VM to my wireless adapter (which I've disabled), but many of the things I've read say that you cannot bridge across a wireless adapter.

Thanks for any pointers.

My win7 VM was created/defined by my use of the GUI tool that came with KVM.  If I hover over the icon it says 'Virtual Machine Manager'.  I have a bridge already setup.  It works for a wired connection and if the Model Type in the /etc/libvirt/qemu/win7.xml file parameter is rtl8139.  If I use the Virtual Machine Manager or the nano text editor to change it to virtIO, I lose LAN connections for the Ubuntu host and the win7 VM.  Below is the output from ifconfig:

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:62:66:28:84:88  
          inet addr:192.168.1.75  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2602:304:cd91:e710:bd86:dd51:d7dd:bc0a/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::a62:66ff:fe28:8488/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2602:304:cd91:e710:a62:66ff:fe28:8488/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1094 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:79513 (79.5 KB)  TX bytes:18098 (18.0 KB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:62:66:28:84:88  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1483 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:248992 (248.9 KB)  TX bytes:19177 (19.1 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:dff00000-dff20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:217 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:217 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:55759 (55.7 KB)  TX bytes:55759 (55.7 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3a:13:59:8b:2e:07  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

The Ubuntu host and the Win7 VM are both getting their IP address from DHCP. My 'interfaces' section is identical to yours, except for the MAC and the model type.  I gave you wrong info in my last reply.  I am only using nano to look at the text in the win7.xml file.  I am not using it to edit the file.  I am using the Virtual Machine Manager GUI to change the model type between rtl8139 and virtIO.  Once I make a change, I confirm the win7.xml file shows the new model type value by using nano to open the file and look at it.

Sorry, but I'm having difficulty pasting the xml file in to the edit window.  when I do, I can see the entire file in the edit window, but only two lines show up in the saved edit.  I think it maybe trying to interpret the file and stripping out the special characters.  I can't find instructions on how to paste an entire file.  Is there a way to attach the file?  BTW - Thanks again for your help with this issue.

Comment: What are you using to define your VM? Or are you trying to edit your existing VM configuration? I can help with `virt-install` or `virsh edit`, but not with `virt-manager`. Do you have a bridge already set up? Please edit your question and add output from `ifconfig` on the 14.10 host.

Comment: You can not use the nano text editor directly on an .xml definition file, you need to use `virsh edit`, as it does some checks and stuff on exit from the edit phase. However, you can set `virsh edit` to use the nano editor for the edit phase.

Comment: Hmmm.. Post your entire win7.xml file, the version after the change. You make the change with the VM off, and then start it afterwards, right? I'll also post my entire .xml file in my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for a windows guest, you might need to install special drivers for virtio to work properly. Please see these references:
http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Virtio
http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/Download_Drivers
https://launchpad.net/kvm-guest-drivers-windows/+download

The following is from one of my VM's. Your mac address and address lines will/ might be different:

```
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:c1:f1:b8'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

Are you saying that does not work for you?
How does the 192.168.1.0 sub-net get its IP addresses? Via dhcp or static?

For context, below is the entire .xml file:

```
<!--
WARNING: THIS IS AN AUTO-GENERATED FILE. CHANGES TO IT ARE LIKELY TO BE
OVERWRITTEN AND LOST. Changes to this xml configuration should be made using:
  virsh edit desk_tt
or other application using the libvirt API.
-->

<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>desk_tt</name>
  <uuid>4235912f-1d46-8866-22ba-c91bfe2a86b7</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>8388608</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>8388608</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-1.7'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/media/newhd/desk_tt.img'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:c1:f1:b8'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' listen='0.0.0.0'>
      <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type='vmvga' vram='16384' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```